# Were there multiple resistance groups in This is Not My Life, or just one?

Tags: this-is-not-my-life

In *[This is Not My Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_Is_Not_My_Life)* groups from outside Waimoana came into the community and kidnapped (or saved, depending on your point of view) people.  There was also a group working on extracting Alec later in the season.

Are these the same group?  I wasn't really clear on whether there was one "resistance" group that was trying to rescue people and were also helping Alec for some reason, or whether there were multiple groups with conflicting (overlapping?) goals.

<sub>If this wasn't answered in Season 1 and left for Season 2 to explain, then that's a valid answer.  My impression was that it was meant to be clear, though.</sub>

Comment: Just going to say I'm happy someone watched this series from my home country :)

Comment: Hmm, does this count as sci-fi or fantasy?

Comment: I would say Sci-fi. It's set in the future and the plot includes fictional future technology.

Comment: @Randal'Thor are you asking whether it is sci-fi or whether it is fantasy (i.e. trying to put it in one genre), or asking whether it is either of sci-fi or fantasy (ie. trying to figure out if it belongs on the site)? If the latter, there is absolutely no question that it does (have you seen the show?). If the former, then it's predominately sci-fi, but the line between the two is nearly always blurry as you would know.

Comment: @TonyMeyer I was asking the latter, having read the Wikipedia description and not seen anything particularly sci-fi or fantasy there. I haven't seen the show, so I accept your better judgement :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor It's a pretty decent show - you should give it a watch some time (if it's available where you are). Although it never got a S2, and does end with a lot unresolved.

Answer (score 4):

The 'terrorist' group is called Recall, as can be validated 
[here, see episode description](http://www.australiantelevision.net/newzealand/this-is-not-my-life/episodes.html) and [here, see episode 11 descriptions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_Is_Not_My_Life),

These two webpages and added to the fact there are only a handful of players and the group was named, I think it is safe to say they are or were one group.

But, on the other hand, there are usually people with differing motives even within the same group, so I could see an unexpected plot twist coming, double agents, shifting allegiances, etc.

EDIT: I would be remiss not to add that I scoured the internet with search robots, and so I feel there is no official answer from writers or interviews regarding this topic.